# How to save data to json file and send to server with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, server, alamofire

I want to get json file from server(local apache), show it contents in UITextView, then add elements and upload back to the server. I have load json contents in UITextView, add one more element and convert to JSON type. Tried to upload on server but it didn't upload file.

My code of load data:

```
func loadData() {
    AF.request("http://localhost/cheerfulNutApache/nuts.json", parameters: header).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let response = JSON(value)
                self.textView.text = "\(response)"

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                break
        }
    }
}
```

My code of upload:

```
let data = textView.text!

    let decode = JSON.init(parseJSON: data)
    print(type(of: decode))

    AF.request("http://localhost/cheerfulNutApache/swift.json", method: .post, parameters: decode).validate().response { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Successful")
            print(response)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Also I google over this question but find only how to upload image and not json. So I need some help with this or advice.

UPD: add AF upload function output

```
[Request]: POST http://localhost/cheerfulNutApache/swift.json
[Request Body]: 
None
[Response]: 
[Status Code]: 200
[Headers]:
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 17:29:31 GMT
Etag: "0-5a188e7f87fc0"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 17:24:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) PHP/7.3.9
[Response Body]: 
None
[Data]: None
[Network Duration]: 0.08196401596069336s
[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s
[Result]: success(nil)
Swift.Result<Swift.Optional<Foundation.Data>, Alamofire.AFError>.success(nil)
```

Comment: Here you are trying to post a json to the server. To upload a json file is different you would have to upload as formdata multipart.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Alamofire Documentations](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#uploading-data-to-a-server), in order to upload files/data, you have to use `AF.upload(...) {...}` instead of `AF.request(...) {...}`.

I think you have to change your upload code to:

```swift
// Convert String to Data
//NOTE: this does NOT check text to be a valid JSON string.
let data = textView.text!.data(using: .utf8)!
let method: HTTPMethod = ... // Default value for `method` is `.post`.
let headers: HTTPHeaders = .../ If you have to set custom HTTP headers.

AF.upload(data, to: "http://localhost/cheerfulNutApache/swift.json", method: method, headers: headers)
  .validate()
  .response { (response) in

    ...

}
```

If your request method is `.post`, and you don't have to set `HTTPHeaders`, you can simply use this:

```
AF.upload(data, to: "http://localhost/cheerfulNutApache/swift.json")
    .validate()
    .response { (response) in

    ...

}
```

**Edited**: second argument of `upload` method should named `to:`. Also you can omit setting `method` to `.post`, because default value for `method` is `.post`.

Comment: I tried your code, but Xcode said that I can't add anything else to function except data and URL

Comment: What is version of using AF?

Comment: AF version 5.0.2

Comment: Oops! Second argument of method should named `to:`. I edited my answer. check it out.

Comment: I got an error: Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:interceptor:fileManager:)'. Maybe it's because of AF version?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. It was a mistake. I edited my answer, and it'll work.

Comment: I run code but see that data isn't sending (add code to question)